# New way to find taylor series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\int \frac{1}{1-x}dx=-ln(1-x)$$
And $$\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^n dx= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-ln(1-x)$$ Is this a new way to find power series for functions?

Comment: Well, it works for THIS function, but how would you handle, say $\sin x$?

Comment: It is not exactly a "new" way of finding power series. It is a way that is sometimes used.

Comment: Plus you have to take care, why you are allowed to switch the sum and the integral.

Comment: No, but good for you for discovering that method. You can legally integrate and differentiate term by term in the interval of convergence.